# How to build this Postgres aggregation query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Schema:

- `locations` (`id`)
- `conversations` (`id`, `location_id`)
- `messages` (`id`, `conversation_id`)

I want to get the number of messages per day per location, in this structure:

```
location_id | data
------------------
1           | 2021-01-01=5,2021-01-02=11,2021-01-03=4,...
              ^ date     ^ num messages that day
```

I can get this data for one location, as follows:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(CAST(pm.created_at AS VARCHAR), 1, 10) AS day,
    COUNT(pm.id)
FROM messages pm
JOIN conversations c ON c.id = pm.conversation_id AND c.location_id = 89
GROUP BY day
```

Gives e.g.:

```
day        | count
------------------
2021-01-01 | 5
...
```

But I can't figure out how to do it per location in one query, i.e. aggregate. Here's my best effort, which gives an error:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG((
    SELECT CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(CAST(pm.created_at AS VARCHAR), 1, 10),
        '=',
        COUNT(pm.id)
    )
    FROM messages pm
    JOIN conversations c ON c.id = pm.conversation_id AND c.location_id = l.id
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CAST(pm.created_at AS VARCHAR), 1, 10)
), ',') AS data
FROM locations l
```

That gives:

```
 more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

...which I've looked into, but can't seem to fathom. If I was using MySQL I'd just use `GROUP_CONCAT` but I can't figure out the Postgres route to doing this.

Comment: Have a look at `string_agg()`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-aggregate.html#:~:text=string_agg(expression%2C%20delimiter)

Comment: I have, and that's what I'm using. Yes, I realise it can't take an int as an argument, but I'm not even at that error point yet. The error I'm currently on I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed in my comment that you are using `string_agg()`.

Instead of using a subquery in your select, please try something like this:

```
with location_day as (
  select location_id, 
         to_char(pm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS day,
         count(pm.id) as message_count
    from messages pm
         join conversations c 
           on c.id = pm.conversation_id 
   group by location_id, day
)
select location_id, 
       string_agg(day||'='||message_count, ',' order by day) as data
  from location_day
 group by location_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=02f7461db88eac50119280a7c53a6aaf)*